# ¿Cómo crear un archivo Excel desde aplicación Windows Forms C#, ejecutar código Excel y luego cerrar el archivo sin guardar?

Tags: c#, excel, windows-forms

He visto que muchas personas hacen cosas similares pero no exactamente igual.

Necesito poder ejecutar código Excel tal como `=1+2` que me regrese 3 o `=SQRT(3^2+4^2)` y regrese 5.
Busqué como hacerlo sin necesidad de abrir un archivo Excel pero solo encontré como ejecutar funciones individualmente pero necesito hacerlo a partir de un string y poder ejecutar varias funciones y operaciones anidadas.

Para resolverlo hice que el código creara una aplicación Excel, le agregara un libro, luego agregar el código que quiero a la celda (1,1) y luego poner el valor de esa misma celda en el texto del Form (es para probar) y funcionó el código regresa muy bien la respuesta pero lo veo muy impráctico porque tiene que crear un archivo cada vez que ejecuta un código y lo peor es que deja un proceso de Excel que solo he podido cerrar manualmente con administrador de tareas o a cerrar la aplicación WinForms.
el codigo que usé fue:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion_excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libro = aplicacion_excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);
libro.Sheets[1].Columns[1].Cells[1] = textBox1.Text;
Text = libro.Sheets[1].Columns[1].Cells[1].value.ToString();
libro.Close(false);
aplicacion_excel.Quit();
```

Nota: textBox1 contiene el código que se quiere ejecutar por ejemplo "=1+2" o "=SQRT(3^2+4^2)" y la salida se guarda en el texto del Form, en el caso de los códigos anteriores se imprime 3 y 5 respectivamente.

¿Alguien tiene una mejor forma para ejecutar código Excel o un código que abra un archivo Excel, ejecute código y cierre el archivo sin dejar procesos de Excel?

ya he intentado muchas cosas y siguen generándose procesos Excel que para colmo se acumulan si se ejecutan varias formulas.

Doy gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final, lo único que funcionó fue matar todos los procesos de nombre "EXCEL" con propiedad "MainWindowTitle" igual a "" (string de longotud 0):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion_excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Text = aplicacion_excel.Evaluate(textBox1.Text).ToString();
aplicacion_excel.Quit();

foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process clsProcess in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Equals("EXCEL") && (clsProcess.MainWindowTitle == ""))
    {
        clsProcess.Kill();
    }
}
```

Mando un especial agradecimiento a Yussef por la aportación de que no era necesario crear un libro.

Answer (score 1):

1.- No es necesario crear un libro, puedes hacer simplemente `aplicacion_excel.evaluate("3+2")`

2.- Para cerrar una librería del tipo `COM`, usas lo siguiente:

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(aplicacion_excel);
```

3.- Puedes usar `IDisposable` en conjunto con el `using` para determinar cuando cerrar el excel

Aquí un ejemplo

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using var eval = new Eval();
        Console.WriteLine(eval.ToDoble("=3+4")); //7
        Console.WriteLine(eval.ToDoble("3+4"));  //7
        Console.WriteLine(eval.ToDoble("=SQRT(3^2+4^2)")); //5
    }
}

public class Eval : IDisposable
{
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new();

    public object ToObject(string expresion)
    {
        return excel.Evaluate(expresion);
    }

    public double ToDoble(string expresion) => (double)ToObject(expresion);
    public int ToInt(string expresion) => Convert.ToInt32(ToDoble(expresion));
    public string ToString(string expresion) => ToObject(expresion).ToString();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (excel != null)
        {
            excel.Quit();
            _ = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ayuda mucho saber que no es necesario abrir un libro, gracias por eso. Pero cuando intento ese código, pasa lo mismo de que aparece un proceso de Excel y no se detiene (solo cuando dejo de ejecutar la winform app), lo bueno es que ya no se acumulan los procesos de Excel, intenté ejecutando la función Dispose() manualmente después de evaluar una expresión pero no se detiene el preceso de Excel y al intentar usar la función ToObject nuevamente arece el error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: 'No se puede utilizar un objeto COM que se ha separado de su RCW subyacente.'

Comment: @Manuelduv Esto es porque el código anterior estaba pensado para un uso y reciclar la misma clase Eval. He actualizado el código para que eso no suceda