# Liberar Memoria RAM desde VB.NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, manejo-de-memoria

estoy desarrollando un programa que importe los datos de un archivo excel a un DATAGRIDVIEW en VB.NET, los datos se cargan mediante un datatable

```
Dim dtMNG As New DataTable
cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM  [" & hoja & "$] ", conn)
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
da.Fill(dtMNG)
ds.Tables.Add(dtMNG)
dtMNG.TableName = "dsMNG"
DGVExcel.DataSource = dtMNG
```

Funciona muy bien, el problema se ve en el monitor de recursos de la PC, si comenzó con 50% de RAM  antes de cargar el archivo excel, despues de cargar llega al 60%, lo cual me parece normal dada la cantidad de datos a cargar.
Lo lógico seria que despues de cerrar el programa el consumo de meroria RAM baje a 50%, ya que en toeria las variables que el programa creo en ejecucion se "eliminan", pero al cerrar el programa la memoria sigue en 60%, vuelvo a ejecutar el programa y cargar el archivo excel y aumenta la memoria RAM a 70% y asi hasta saturar el sistema.

He probado limpiando los datos del datatable

```
ds.Tables("dsMNG").Clear()
```

Pero, al ejecutar en el monitor de recursos, la memoria RAM sigue al 70%, no consigo liberar la memoria RAM despues de cerrar el programa, esto es crítico ya que el programa al final colgaría el sistema. Algún buen samaritano del código que sepa orientarnos en este puno?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

.Net utiliza un sistema de liberación de memoria llamado **Garbage Collector** (GC para los amigos) (otros lenguajes como JAVA utilizan la misma técnica)

Antes de la creación del GC era el desarrollador quien tenia la responsabilidad de liberar y administrar la memoria. Con la llegada del GC esta preocupación ya no es necesaria.

En general el GC limpia la memoria cuando no existe un puntero señalando a tal espacio, es decir basta con hacer `mivariable=null`, o como en tu caso que la aplicación ha sido cerrada. Para ser más claro el GC opera en un proceso separado y no depende de tu aplicación, por lo que puede operar con tu aplicación luego de haber sido cerrada

**¿Cuando realiza esta recolección?**

En la práctica (y en mi experiencia) es cuando se le da la gana, según la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions-for-a-garbage-collection), las condiciones son:

- El sistema tiene poca memoria física.
- La memoria utilizada por los objetos asignados en el montón administrado supera un umbral aceptable. Este umbral se ajusta continuamente a medida que se ejecuta el proceso.
- Se llama al método `GC.Collect()` manualmente.

El punto es que esas serían las condiciones, pero el algoritmo que evalua que esas condiciones se cumplan es bastante más complejo. E incluso en el último caso donde puedes llamar a recolectar manualmente usando `GC.Collect()` tampoco quiere decir que esto se ejecute inmediatamente, ya que pasa a una cola de prioridad. Por lo que uno tiene bastante poco control de la administración de memoria.

En resumen, no deberías preocuparte anticipadamente. No tienes ningún error, el sistema no se ha colgado y no hay nada que indique que la recolección de basura no está funcionando correctamente.

[Documentación Garbage Collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/)

Comment: He probado manuamente GC.Collect() sin ningun resultado en la memoria RAM.

Comment: @TomWelling Es justamente lo que te estoy diciendo.  Si bien dicen que GC.Collect()   llama al colector, esto no es así. Existe un algoritmo que ejecuta la limpieza cuando aquel algoritmo determina que es necesario. Tu no debes preocuparte de la memoria que eso se hace solo

Comment: Otra forma sería finalizar procesos, he notado que abre demasiado el proceso EXCEL.EXE con diferentes PID, veo que eso es el responsable de la RAM y lentitud.

Comment: taskkill /IM EXCEL.EXE /F finaliza el proceso EXCEL, lo malote de esto es que finaliza todos mis EXCEL abiertos también, una forma sería por el PID, pero cada proceso tiene uno diferente. Alguna forma de obtener el PID EXCEL del proceso creado por el programa?

Comment: @TomWelling ¿Porqué tu programa tendría que abrir o ejecutar `EXCEL.EXE` para trabajar con archivos de Excel?

Comment: @TomWelling Espera un poco....estas usando interop ??????

Comment: Si es así, mira esta publicación https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/595576/301324

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por tu respuesta, lo que sucede es que estoy importando los datos de un excel a un datagridview y lo hago con OLDBConnection, es ahi donde el programa abre por cada hoja que lee un proceso EXCEL.EXE

Comment: Cuando no se tiene ningun excel abierto y ejecuto el programa para importar, no se abre la aplicacion de excel, pero en segundo plano se abre los procesos. Pero cuando tengo un excel cualquierta abierto, y ejecuto el programa para importar, ahi  es donde mas claro se abre el libro de excel que estoy importando. Eso no es bueno.

Comment: @TomWelling Es otro escenario el que planteas, porque de tu pregunta se entiende que es la aplicación la que queda consumiendo memoria, y no un proceso externo como lo es EXCEL.EXE. Te insisto que leas el link que te puse arriba, además te sugiero no trabajar con librerías COM que por ahí va el fondo del problema

Comment: @Yussef ok gracias, lo tendré en cuenta.